# Dispose will dispose objects that are still referenced?

Tags: c#, linq

Definition:

```
public class A
{
   List<B> B { get; set; }
}
public class B
{
   public List<C> C { get; set; }
}
public class C
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
var model = new A();
DbContext db = new DbContext()
var AllBs = (from b in db.Bs select b).ToList();
model.B = AllBs;  //line x
db.Dispose()
```

At line x, I can see all the instances and details of AllBs.C.  However, once past the `Dispose` line, **SOMETIMES** model.B lose all references to C and if I try to reference it I get:

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used
>   for operations that require a connection.

It happens only sometimes, more often than not.  Did I do anything wrong?

After thought: I think the sometimes is caused by my use of the VS debugger. If I had inspected the contents the data would have been enumerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting that exception because when you try to access related navigation property entity framework will try to populate the instances using DbContext's connection instance (in lazy loading mode).

You would like to use eager loading in such a cases:

```
var model = new A();
DbContext db = new DbContext()
var AllBs = (from b in db.Bs.Include("C") select b).ToList();
model.B = AllBs;  //line x
db.Dispose()
```

Calling [`Include`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) would here load instances of `B` type with collection loaded with related instances of type `C`

Comment: It works!.  It should be `.Include("Cs")`, as my declaraction was actually `public List<C> Cs`.